# A hidden puzzle link

Tags: cipher

I have left you a line to a puzzle below this sentence:

WKLVLVDUHGKHUULQJORO

So? What are you waiting for, go!

Hint:

> Think like a Roman!j

Second Hint:

> Who said that’s binary?

[image: sdvwhelqfrp7ytvtl8d]

Answer (score 3):

> Doing rot23 on the words gives you **THISISAREDHERRINGLOL**

And

> I found this in the edit page "sdvwhelqfrpjqxt3bjy" and Rot23 give **

And

> This is hidden in the edit page **https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd5Yv.jpg** which is a white picture.

Comment: Well @QuantumTwinkie, aren't you fast!

Comment: @RohitJose any closer?

Comment: If you rot13(cynl jvgu gur oevtugarff/pbagenfg ba gur vzntr, vg ybbxf yvxr vg pbhyq unir cneg bs n DE pbqr va vg. hfvat n urk rqvgbe ba vg qbrfa'g fhttrfg gur cerfrapr bs zhpu ryfr), but I'm likely wrong about that last part

Comment: Ohh, that's an interesting find!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Who said that’s binary? Also I have reset the puzzle

Comment: The quick brown fox jumps over thirteen lazy dogs is starter encoding example for website cyrptii.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after the edit,

> the link becomes https://pastebin.com/7vqsqi8a. On that page is some binary in groups of 5, and some letters. I'm not sure what's next, but this is mostly just so that people don't go in the wrong direction.